# How to countifs in python, and directly create column in data frame (grouping with multiple columns)

Tags: excel, pandas, group-by, multiple-columns, countif

currently Im using excel or spreadsheet to do `countifs`, the questions is how can we get this result in `pandas`

[image]

---

currently I successfully use this method

```
item_view['size'] = item_view.groupby('status_id')['date'].transform(len)
qfilter_1 = qgrid.show_grid(item_view)
qfilter_1
```

but the result is count all match, what im trying to achieve is in a picture, really appreciate your help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
item_view['i'] = np.arange(len(item_view))
item_view['countifs'] = item_view.groupby(['status id','date']).transform('count')
```

which `prints`:

```
         date status id   i  countifs
0  2020-11-30        AA   0         2
1  2020-11-30        DD   1         2
2  2020-11-30        AA   2         2
3  2020-11-30        DD   3         2
4  2020-11-30        EE   4         1
5  2020-11-30        FF   5         1
6  2020-11-23        GG   6         2
7  2020-11-23        DD   7         2
8  2020-11-23        EE   8         1
9  2020-11-23        FF   9         1
10 2020-11-23        GG  10         2
11 2020-11-23        DD  11         2
```

and then `drop` the new `i` column we created:

```
item_view.drop('i',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

to get exactly what you need:

```
         date status id  countifs
0  2020-11-30        AA         2
1  2020-11-30        DD         2
2  2020-11-30        AA         2
3  2020-11-30        DD         2
4  2020-11-30        EE         1
5  2020-11-30        FF         1
6  2020-11-23        GG         2
7  2020-11-23        DD         2
8  2020-11-23        EE         1
9  2020-11-23        FF         1
10 2020-11-23        GG         2
11 2020-11-23        DD         2
```

and then, if you want to keep only unique rows, you can `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Hi Thanks for help, but I think I have same result by using your query, by using above method the result will count all data so each row with match data will have same result i.e
3
3
3


what im trying to do is:
3
2
1

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data, so that I can recreate your ```dataframe``` and try to figure it out?

Comment: Hey, I put the data here, 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXrl_JRTkYKG1mJCk2XN5zpbjB94mG_W-TLodHDI8_M/edit#gid=0

sorry newbie to use stack  overflow

Comment: wow --- super! thank you @sophods amazing, really appreciate your help....

Comment: No problem. I am also a newbie to SO

Comment: Hi Bro, Sorry I think I missed something, the result still same, my expectation is index 0 AA | 30 Nov 2020 | result is 2 because it detecting another AA | 30 Nov 2020 in index 2.

but in index 2: my expectation is 1, because formula will not counting index 1 and 0 and so on

Comment: I am not sure I understand 100% what you want to do, but why don't you drop index 2? and then you will be only left with index 0? Now there are duplicates, why would you like to keep duplicates and have them as 1 in countifs?